# CICD pipeline for MAUI using Gitlab CI is not generating app icon for iOS app

Tags: ios, .net, gitlab-ci, maui, cicd

I'm working on a solution to develop the CICD Pipeline for dotnet MAUI project which is using following environment.

1. Development machine - MAC OS Ventura 13.5.1
2. dotnet SDK - 7.0.302
3. MAUI- iOS application targate : 11

**Issue** - Following command is generating ipa but without the icon and so while uploading the file to Test Flight, validation is getting fail.

I'm using following dotnet command.

```
dotnet publish sample.csproj -f net7.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifiers=ios-arm64
```

Do you have any input, what could be the possible reason for this failure.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Android build produce an icon or you are only targeting iOS so haven't tried it? Also does it have an icon on iOS when deploying directly to a device or a simulator?

I found that issue on .NET MAUI's github. It seems to be a problem with rasterizer on iOS when the svg size is not divisible by 8.

That didn't work for me, but might be worth giving a shot.

I was having the same issue but for me it was a missing Info.plist file. Because I am working with different ones per configuration, the Development configuration in MAUI.csproj wasn't specifying an existing one.

[App Icon for iOS is not created when app icon is not a multiplier by 8 #9067](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9067)